# What does the algorithm do? What is role of isGood?

Tags: algorithm, output, dijkstra

I know this is Dijkstra's algorithm but I am not able to figure out the role of `IsGood`.

**Input:** Undirected graph `G=(V;E)` with edge weights `le > 0` for all `e` belongs to `E` and a vertex `s` belongs to `V`.

**Output:** For every vertex `v`, a Boolean value `IsGood[v]`

```
for each vertex v do
    cost[v]  = infinite // integer array indexed by elements of V
    IsGood[v] =  TRUE
end for

cost[s] = 0
MakeEmptyPriorityQueue(Q)

for each v belongs to V do
    InsertPriorityQueue(Q; v; cost[v])
end for

while IsNotEmpty(Q) do
    u  = DeleteMin(Q)
    for each edge e = (u; v) belongs to E, leaving u do
        if cost[v] > cost[u] + le then
            cost[v]  = cost[u] + le
            DecreaseKey(Q; v; cost[v])
            IsGood[v] = IsGood[u]
        else
            IsGood[v] = FALSE
        end if
    end for
end while
```

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is used to find the shortest path between two nodes. See [Dijkstra's algorithm on wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj5j4OC05zsAhUjzlkKHedXCUEQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDijkstra%2527s_algorithm&usg=AOvVaw14iNMPx1mzwSQQ4UNocSSt)

Comment: Yes, but can you please tell what is IsGood doing here?

Comment: Where did you find this? It looks like this algorithm attempts to mark vertices lying on the shortest path, but it doesn't do so correctly.